# Javascript .replace being re-written on page load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, fullcalendar

So I'm not really sure how to explain this, so I will just provide an example.  I'm using `fullCalendar` jquery calendar to populate events in a calendar on my page. `fullCalendar` has a method called 'eventClick' which you can then run some code.

Basically I'm trying to go to a page on my site (the event page) when clicked and passing it the URL like so:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events:array,
    eventClick: function(event) {
        if( event.url ) {
            window.open(event.url);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

event.url is a string that I'm pulling in from Wordpress and is displayed like so:

```
http://sitedomain.com/?post_type=events&p=340
```

## The Problem

When I click on an event, the URL gets encoded differently and displays like this:

```
http://sitedomain.com/?post_type=events&#038;p=340
```

where `&` gets replaced with `&#038;` which then obviously doesn't go to the correct page on my site.  I rewrote my click method like so but I still get the same results -

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events:array,
    eventClick: function(event) {
        var page = event.url;
        page = page.replace('&#038;', '&');
        if( page ) {
            window.open(page);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Anyone have a solution?

Thanks,

Comment: Where exactly is the "&" being changed into a "&#038;" ? That looks like HTML special character escaping.

Comment: Oops, I updated code. When I console.log 'page', it's fine - before the page reloads. When the page changes, the URL gets rewritten back to &#038; instead of just &.

Comment: You can use `page = $('<div>').html(page).text();` to un-escape ALL html special characters in a string, just before you pass the URL to `window.open`.

Comment: That is basically doing the same thing as my javascript .replace.  When logged, the URL looks great, its when the page actually tries to go to that URL, it's like the browser is rewriting it back. I hope I'm making myself clear...

Comment: There is something else going on in your code, then. Try to step through it using your browser's JavaScript debugger and watch the variables. Your code sample is too small for us to deduce the problem.

Comment: try a different browser. Are you using other js libraries besides of jquery? try disabling them and look if it changes something. It's not the usual behaviour. Isolate code and run it on a js console (e.g. Firebug, Chrome), can you reproduce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel stupid.

I guess I failed to mention that I was using `window.location.href` whereas in my example question I was using `window.open`.

The problem was that I was getting the syntax incorrect for `window.location.href` using it like so:

```
window.location.href(event.url);
```

instead of

```
window.location.href = event.url;
```

Reminder to get your syntax right and then things will work like you think they are suppose to... :) Thanks for the help all.